# Proper way to deploy Java Hibernate Project

Tags: java, hibernate, deployment

When I try to export a JavaSE + Hibernate project, the end result is I get a xyz.jar file, which can be extracted. In that extracted file, I get a bunch of .class files, which is okay but the problem is I or anyone can open up hibernate.config.xml and check the database connection settings, which might look something like this:

```
...
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
...
```

suppose if the db is hosted on some server instead of local host, then anyone can potentially access my data just by looking at hibernate config. Is there anyway to prevent this? Or am i doing it wrong. Is there anyway i can make deployment more secure?
(I am not used to deployment part of software development lifecycle)

Comment: That's why you don't give it away to other people. Either run it yourself on a server where only you have access, or distribute it so those who use it must set up their own database to use it. If you must share a database over the internet, you can't give direct access. You'll have to provide a backend that handles the DB access, and communicate over a socket with that backend.

Comment: @Kayaman There must be a way around it, right? What you are saying kinda  means 2-tier architecture is insecure.

Comment: That's not a 2-tier architecture. That's a 1-tier architecture with a remote database. You can't give direct access to a database if you don't want the user to have direct access to the database. You need a client-server architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Well my way around it was using Java code for Hibernate configuration instead of xml. In this way, when someone extracts the .jar file of your project, they will see bytecodes of configuration, instead of readable codes of xml.